# How to change the default format in Numbers?

Tags: numbers, formatting

When using Numbers and I want to underline a cell, the default format is outlining the whole cell.  I want the default format in Numbers to be only an underline not a box. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If by "underline a cell" you mean just a bottom border, this is done in the **Cell** tab of the inspector.

- Select the cell(s) you wish to apply the bottom border to.
- In the **Cell** tab on the **Inspector** select the border formatting.
- There are several dropdowns that allow you to choose the style and weight of the bottom border.  See screenshots below.
- Once you get your sheet the way you like it, save it as a template for future use.  (This can be your 'default')

If, however, you want the data or content only underlined, this is in the **Text** tab of the **Inspector**

- Select the cell with your data
- Apply the underline either by selecting it or using keyboard <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

[image: Bottom border]

[image: Apply Underline]